# How do I change the spacing between words in italics/bold/etc?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, latexmk

I have tried to use `\fontdimen2\font=0.75ex` but that only changes the size of the regular font, while italics and bold retain the same spacing.
I know that I can use something like `\fontdimen2\italic=0ex` if I define it with the `\font\italic=<font_filename>` command before, but I do not know what `<font_filename>` to use to affect italics/bold.

I am using pdfLaTeX on LaTeXmk.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to select the font `\textit{\fontdimen2\font=0.75ex}` for example.

`\font` in the form that you showed always references the currently selected font.